# aggregate across multiple vectors, retain entries that only have NAs for particular vectors

Tags: r

generate some example `data`

```
site<- c(12,12,12,12,45,45,45,45)
horizon<-c('A','A','B','C','A','A','B','C')
value1<- c(19,14,3,2,18,19,4,5)
value2<- c(NA,NA,3,2,NA,NA,4,5)
data<-data.frame(site,horizon,value1,value2)
```

say I use the aggregate function to summarize value 1 by site and horizon

```
aggregate(value1~site+horizon,data=data,FUN=mean)
```

R prints:

```
  site horizon value
1   12       A  16.5
2   45       A  18.5
3   12       B   3.0
4   45       B   4.0
5   12       C   2.0
6   45       C   5.0
```

However, if I aggregate by both vectors, it drops out all A horizons since they dont have data for `value2`

```
aggregate(.~site + horizon,data=data,FUN=mean)
  site horizon value1 value2
1   12       B      3      3
2   45       B      4      4
3   12       C      2      2
4   45       C      5      5
```

I would like this generate the output from my first aggregate call, with an additional column for `value2` that has NA entries for the A horizons.

Comment: try `aggregate(..., na.action=na.pass)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
aggregate(.~site + horizon,data=data,FUN=mean, na.action=na.pass)
```

Comment: oh my god this is exactly what I needed. I am dumb.